# Web scraping with getElementsByTagName()

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

I want to import restaurant data like Restaurant name, phone number, website & address to excel but unfortunately I am getting ads & garbage data. I have created a code using http://automatetheweb.net/vba-getelementsbytagname-method/ website but it is not helping out. Please rectify the issue in my code. 
Website:https://www.yellowpages.com/atlanta-ga/attorneys
Please donot refer json as it is not working on other webs.

```
Sub Yellowcom()
    'Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlELe As IHTMLElement
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim URL As String
    Dim URLParameter As String
    Dim page As Long
    Dim links As Object
    Dim IE As Object


    i = 1

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    'Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True
    URL = "https://www.yellowpages.com/atlanta-ga/attorneys"
    'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    For page = 2 To 4

        If page > 1 Then URLParameter = "?page=" & page

        IE.navigate URL & URLParameter

        ' Wait for the browser to load the page
        Do Until IE.readyState = 4

            DoEvents

        Loop

        Set HTML = IE.document
        Set links = HTML.getElementsByClassName("info")

    For Each htmlELe In links

        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlELe.Children(0).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlELe.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
            .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlELe.Children(2).textContent
            .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlELe.Children(2).querySelector("a[href]")
             'links2 = htmlELe.getElementsByClassName("links")(1)
           ' .Range("D" & i).Value = links2.href


        End With
    i = i + 1

    Next htmlELe

    Next page

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Required Output should be like this
[image]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting adds in website division and address field is giving page address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use xhr rather than a browser and store data in an array for each page and write that out to sheet. You could really dimension one array to hold all results in advance based on results per page and number of pages but the below is still efficient

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetListings()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, page As Long, html2 As HTMLDocument
    Dim results As Object, headers(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long

    Const START_PAGE As Long = 1
    Const END_PAGE As Long = 2

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    headers = Array("Name", "Phone", "Website", "Address")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set html2 = New HTMLDocument
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For page = START_PAGE To END_PAGE
            .Open "GET", "https://www.yellowpages.com/atlanta-ga/attorneys?page=" & page, False
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            Set results = html.querySelectorAll(".organic .result")
            Dim output(), r As Long
            ReDim output(1 To results.Length, 1 To 4)
            r = 1
            For i = 0 To results.Length - 1
                On Error Resume Next
                html2.body.innerHTML = results.item(i).outerHTML
                output(r, 1) = html2.querySelector(".business-name").innerText
                output(r, 2) = html2.querySelector(".phone").innerText
                output(r, 3) = html2.querySelector(".track-visit-website").href
                output(r, 4) = html2.querySelector(".street-address").innerText & " " & html2.querySelector(".locality").innerText
                On Error GoTo 0
                r = r + 1
            Next
            ws.Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)) = output
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Sample of output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The info class is also used for the advertisements. You first need to go to the collection where the classname is "search-results organic" and in there find all the "info" classes.

This means that you need an extra collection variable:

```
Set HTML = IE.document
Set OrganicLinks = HTML.getElementsByClassName("search-results organic")
Set links = OrganicLinks.item(0).getElementsByClassName("info")
```

For getting the right website, you need to use another reference. It's better to get it by classname, since that one is more unique:

```
On Error Resume Next
.Range("B" & i).Value = htmlELe.getElementsByClassName("track-visit-website")(0).href
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: can you please edit my code as I am new to vba, I will see and learn from edited code

Comment: It is giving error "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Sorry, small mistake. OrganicLinks is a collection of 1 item. so it needs to get the info elements from the first item. I changed it.

Comment: Do you still get advertisements? I tested it and it didn't show advertisements anymore after my change.

Comment: I have just edited my post i need the output like the snap I have shared.

Comment: Yes add issue resolve and you letme know about address field issue

Comment: Edited the answer :)

Comment: This code I have enter after  Set links = OrganicLinks.item(0).getElementsByClassName("info")

Comment: It is working fine with links, i tried On Error Resume Next
.Range("C" & i).Value = htmlELe.getElementsByClassName("phones phone primary")(0).href
On Error GoTo 0   but is not working for number